# Warum verwendet man im Deutschen Ortsadverbien und -pronomen so oft?

Tags: etymology, sociolinguistics

Im Deutschen werden oft Ortsadverbien und -pronomen verwendet, um verschiedenste Dinge zu referenzieren.

- Davon träumst du/ Da träumst du von.
- Ich habe gestern ein Pony geschenkt bekommen. Da habe ich mich sehr gefreut.
- Worüber regst du dich so auf?

In einigen Dialekten geht das sogar noch weiter:

- Der Mann, wo ich gesehen habe, heißt Thomas.
- Wo du angerufen hast, war ich gerade unter der Dusche.

Woher kommt dieses Phänomen?

Ist das Phänomen neu oder im Gegenteil Zeuge einer Zeit, in der weniger konkrete Dinge noch nicht ausgedrückt werden konnten?

EDIT: Da viele anscheinend die Frage nicht verstehen …

- Wie alt ist die Tendenz **da** und **wo** in Kontexten, die NICHT Ort sind, zu verwenden (da-Wörter, Zeit, anderes)?
- Woher kommt diese Tendenz? Ist es Indo-Europäisch?

Bitte bei Close-Votes begründen, was unklar ist, sonst werde ich die Frage erneut stellen.

Comment: "Davon" ist doch kein Ort. Auch ein Pony ist keine Immobilie. Den ersten 2 Beispielen mangelt es sowohl an einem Ort, als auch am "wo". Selbst dann wären 3 Wörter weit entfernt vom in der Überschrift versprochenem `alles`. Ich dachte Du suchst `überall` als ich die Überschrift las.

Comment: Da ist ursprünglich ein Orts-Adverb. Wenn ich ein da-Wort benutze wie davon, dann verwende ich ein Ortsadverb und eine Präposition anstelle von Präposition plus Pronomen. Ein Pony ist keine Immobilie, das ist genau der Punkt. Das Orstadverb da zeigt auf irgendwas (Zeit, Event) aber nicht auf Ort... aber ich ändere die Überschrift... es ist schon ein bisschen unklar vielleicht.

Comment: "Da" und "wo" haben nicht nur einen örtlichen Bezug, sondern auch einen zeitlichen. "Zu dem Zeitpunkt wo du angerufen hast" "In dem Moment habe ich mich sehr gefreut". - "Der Mann, wo ich gesehen habe" ist was anderes, und das ist imho die einzige Frage. - Das allererste Beispiel ist auch was anderes und bedeutet "von dieser Sache"

Comment: Zum historischen Wandel kann ich nichts sagen, aber wenn früher da ein Ortsadverb war, dann ist es das heute offenbar nicht mehr. `Davon` und `darüber` sind ja auch keine Ortsadverbien. Wenn `da` früher ausschließlich Ortsadverb war, hat man es da vielleicht nicht so benutzt wie in Deinen Beispielen?

Comment: @Em1: Ich weiß, dass sie einen zeitlichen Bezug haben. Ich will wissen wieso sie den haben, und ob sie den schon immer haben... das Englische there hat keinen Zeitbezug zum Beispiel

Comment: @userunknown: das ist doch genau meine Frage... ich will wissen, seit wann und warum diese Worte mehr als nur einen Ortsbezug haben.

Comment: warum gibt es hier bitte einen close-vote???

Comment: "Zum Zeitpunkt `als` Emanuel angerufen hat ...", nicht `wo`! There you are!

Comment: @userunknown: Leute sprechen aber mit "wo"... egal ob das richtig ist oder nicht

Comment: Leute wo ich kenne nicht! ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9880/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-emanuel)

Comment: Falls die Frage geschlossen wird, nicht neu stellen, sondern diese grundlegend editieren. Auch wenn der Zusatz jetzt deine Fragestellung deutlicher rüberkommen lässt.

Comment: @Em1: vielleicht bin ich zu doof, aber mir ist echt nicht klar, was hier unklar sein soll

Comment: @userunknown Have a look at http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wo_Fragewort_Relativpronomen#Bedeutung2b - "wo" in this context is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Emanuel: Kannst Du "in einigen Dialekten" spzeifizieren? Für mich muss die Überschrift der Frage dann lauten "Warum verwendet man im Schwäbischen ..." usw., nicht "im Deutschen". Im Dt. heißt es "Als Du angerufen hast..." und "Der Mann den ich sah."

Comment: @userunknown... ich wüsste nicht wozu. In der Frage geht es ganz klar NICHT um diese dialektale Verwendung. Sie dient nur al... ach weißt du was. Warum reagier ich eigentlich.

Comment: @Emanuel: "In einigen Dialekten geht das sogar noch weiter..." - Zitat aus der Frage. Die zwei Beispiele davor: "Davon träumst Du". "Davon" soll ein Ortsadverb sein? Wie das?  "Da habe ich mich sehr gefreut." (Da: Gestern, daraufhin) - welches ist das Ortsadverb?

Comment: @userunknown... das Ortsadverb ist "da". Es wird hier nicht als Ortsadverb verwendet, aber im Grunde seines Wesens ist es das. Genauso wie "wo" nach einem Ort fragt aber in "wovon" nicht örtlich verwendet wird.

Comment: @Emanuel: Wieso sollte ein Wort ein Wesen haben, an dessen Grund sich eine Spezialisierung findet? Gibt es dafür Belege? Ist das die herrschende Meinung der Sprachwissenschaft? "Daher, darum, davon" sind jetzt keine exotischen Begriffe und nicht sehr neu. Als Laie sehe ich keinen Grund sie auf ein räumlich verstandenes "da" zurückzuführen.

Comment: @userunknown...  Ich will diese Frage nicht ausdiskutieren. Wenn du der Meinung bist, dass meine Annahme falsch ist, dann mach eine Antwort und schreib das da. Und da kannst du dann gleich auch auf "wo" eingehen, das du hier fein ignoriert hast.

Comment: @Emanuel: Das wo habe ich nicht fein ignoriert, sondern darauf hingewiesen, dass es, da es unter "Dialekt" in die Diskussion eingeführt wurde, nicht das Deutsche als Ganzes betrifft.

Comment: _Der Mann, wo ich gesehen habe,_ Ich gehe mich mal erschiessen

Answer (score 10):

Laut dem etymologischen Wörterbuch nach Pfeiffer (http://www.dwds.de/?qu=da) hat das heutige "da" mehrere Ursprünge:

Örtlicher Gebrauch:

> da Adv., das auf einen (vom Standort des Sprechers entfernten) Punkt
>   im Raume hinweist [...]. Ahd. thār (8. Jh.), asächs. thā̌r, mhd. dā(r), mnd. dār, mnl. > daer, dare, nl. daar, aengl. þǣr, engl. there und mit gekürztem Vokal got. anord. þar, > schwed. där sind (wie das Richtungsadverb ahd. thara, mhd. dare, dar, s. dar-) mit r
>   -Erweiterung zu dem auch in der (s. d.) vorliegenden Pronominalstamm ie. *te-, *to- gebildet; vgl. außerhalb des Germ. aind. tárhi
>   ‘damals’.

Zeitlicher Gebrauch:

> da Adv. zur Angabe eines bestimmten Zeitpunktes ( ‘zu jener Zeit, in
>   diesem Augenblick’) und Konj.; ahd. (8. Jh.), asächs. thō, mhd. mnd.
>   dō, mnl. doe, afries. thā, aengl. þā. Diese für das Westgerm. bezeugte
>   Bildung (anders got. þan ‘dann’ sowie anord. þā ‘da, damals’ aus *þan,
>   s. dann) schließt sich wie ¹da (s. d.) an den Pronominalstamm ie.
>   *te-, *to- an; sie ist ursprünglich wohl Akk. Sing. Fem. des Demonstrativpronomens (vgl. got. þō, aind. tā́m, ie. *tām), neben dem
>   vielleicht ein feminines Substantiv mit der Bedeutung ‘Zeit’
>   weggefallen ist.

Und im Spätmittelhochdeutschen (14. Jahrhundert) fallen beide zusammen:

> Vom Spätmhd. an kommt es zum formalen Zusammenfall mit da [U: Angabe eines bestimmten Zeitpunktes], denn das auslautende -r schwindet im Mhd.[...]

Ähnlich aber nicht ganz so "sauber" ist es mit dem heutigen "wo" (Abstammung von einer Reihe von Adverbien aus verschiedenen Zeiten, http://www.dwds.de/?qu=wo). Ich spekuliere hier, dass alte Bedeutungen vor allem in Dialekten übriggeblieben sind.

Comment: [Die Grimms schreiben zu wo](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW24313) ...zur kurzvokalischen form gehören auszer den oben genannten ost- und westgerm. bezeichnungen für 'wo' noch die **lokaladverbia der richtung:** ahd. (h)wara, mhd. und frühnhd. war(e), as. hwar, mnd. (nd.) war und das ostgerm. **fragepronomen** got. arjis, an. hverr 'welcher?' (vgl. das gleichgebildete lit. kurìs 'welcher' aus ku jìs, also wörtlich 'wo er'); ferner ai. kár-hi 'wann?'.

Answer (score 4):

Zur Frage nach dem WO:

Meines Erachtens ist die Verwendung in folgenden Beispielen falsch:

```
Der Mann, wo ich gesehen habe, heißt Thomas.
Wo du angerufen hast, war ich gerade unter der Dusche.
```

Ich kann leider derzeit noch keine Begründung geben, warum es dazu kommt. Es ist schwer auf google danach zu suchen. Meine persönliche Einschätzung ist, dass die korrekte Benutzung der deutschen Sprache im Gesprochenen schnell verloren geht und sich besonders die Verwendung von WO als Ersatz für andere Worte schnell eingeschlichen hat.

Ich suche aber mal einen Artikel und wenn ich ihn gefunden habe, ergänze ich ihn hier.

**Ergänzung**

- [Lernseite zu wo oder als](http://www.mieriesuperklasse.de/seiten/2_unterrichtsseiten/deutsch/wo_oder_als.htm)
- [örtliche Verteilung von als, wie, wo, ...](http://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_7/f12a-b/)

Also wie gesagt, ich kann leider nicht sagen, woher das stammt, aber ich würde mir das nicht angewöhnen ;-)

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wo_Fragewort_Relativpronomen#Bedeutung2b - "wo" seems to be "officially valid".

Comment: Hm.. ja der Duden. Es gibt halt kein Gremium, dass die deutsche Sprache macht. Der Duden hält fest, wie sie sich verändert. Schade, aber kein Wunder, dass es das wo in der Verwendung auch in den Duden geschafft hat.